# Como alterar e manter o mapeamento das classes e propriedades utilizando ADO.net

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net, code-first, ado

Ao utilizar um banco de dados que possuo as tabelas e colunas com nomes como:

**- tb_usuario**

- usu_id
- usu_nome
- usu_data_nasc

**- tb_produto**

- pro_id
- pro_nome
- pro_desc_resumida
- pro_desc_completa

Ao utilizar **ADO.NET Entity Data Model -> EF Designer From Database**, ele cria as classes entities no meu projeto com o mesmo nome das tabelas, e as propriedades com o mesmo nome das colunas do banco de dados. Porem sei que no código não é uma boa prática, e nem quero, ter o nome de propriedades como: **pro_desc_completa**. E sim como: **descricaoCompleta**.

Porem, como faço isso? É possível mapear uma propriedade ou classe, com uma tabela e ter nomes diferentes, utilizando o EF Designer From Database?

Ou qual seria a melhor abordagem a utilizar?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No contexto da sua aplicação, a classe aonde você configura o EF e define os DBSet, também pode customizar outras informações. Você pode sobrescrever o método: `onModelCreating` utilizando fluent API e definir manualmente o mapeamento das suas entidades:

Supondo que:

**tb_usuario**

- usu_id
- usu_nome
- usu_data_nasc

Se transformou em:

```
public class Usuario{
    public int id {get; set; }
    public string nome {get; set; }
    public DateTime dataNascimento {get; set; }
}
```

Você mapearia como:

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);

    modelBuilder.Entity<Usuario>()
        .ToTable("tb_usuario")
        .Property(p => p.id)
        .HasColumnName("usu_id");
}
```

Ou, ainda, pode usar data annotation:

```
[Table("tb_usuario")]
public class Usuario{
    [Column("usu_id")]
    public int id {get; set; }

    [Column("usu_nome")]
    public string nome {get; set; }

    [Column("usu_data_nasc")]
    public DateTime dataNascimento {get; set; }
}
```

Comment: entendi, porém vou ter que fazer o mapeamento assim no modelBuilder para todas as minhas classes, e todas minhas propriedades. Vai ser um trabalho bem árduo. Sei que no java, conseguimos mapear através de um annotation, pensei que no c# teria algo parecido...

Comment: outra questão, é, o meu contexto, é gerado automaticamente pelo ADO.net, e vem com o aviso de que o código pode ser alterado caso seja atualizado o meu model. Portanto não é seguro mexer nele. Então posso criar uma classe, herdar do meu contexto para fazer essa implementação do OnModelCreating?

Comment: Tu pode usar annotation também: [Table("tb_usuario")] decorando sua classe e , [Column("usu_id")] suas propriedades. Vou adicionar a resposta.